# Moving webserver off network with AD Integrated DNS

Tags: active-directory, web-server, internal-dns

My question is simple.  If i change an A record manually in my internal, AD Integrated DNS, will the record be overwritten at some point in the future?

Our internal domain is example.com. Our webserver has the device name WWW. Therefore there is a record for WWW.example.com in our AD Integrated DNS. That means when some visits www.example.com, they get our webserver.

If I manually change this WWW A record to point to an external IP, and leave my local server running for say, another 4 hours, will AD Integrated DNS overwrite my change?

My WWW server has static IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, one you change it, it becomes static and will not be scavenged or updated unless you set scavenging to anything other than 0, or you specifically give the server permissions to the a record, respectively